# Is it possible to max every art and skill without multiplayer?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-x

While playing through my first class, I found it pretty easy to max out most of the skills I was using. Coupled with a lot of exploration, I found myself with a decent amount of BP all the time. Now I'm going through my second class and I'm a bit more worried - there definitely is way less BP going around.

Is it possible to get every art and skill to level 5 in the game? If not, how close can you get?

I'm aware of these ways to get BP:

- get class rank ups
- find field items (mechanical, biological, archaeological)
- play online
- explore new areas (and find new, unexplored territory/sightseeing spots)

It seems like the only one that gives a repeated amount of BP is playing online (which I fully acknowledge), as the other resources are finite. Playing online is fun, but with the frequent disconnects it's more of a nuisance than anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is yes.

Upon beating the game, you unlock support missions (accessible via the back terminal in the BLADE barracks, where you normally do multiplayer interactions).

In here, there are 6 missions (the first 6), giving this amount of BP:

- The Docile Ovis (4)
- The Grand Plot (8)
- Reckless Prone (12)
- Greedy Prone (24)
- Noctilum Nights (48)
- As If a Cloud (60)

The best way to get BP is to repeatedly do the last one - in a good skell, you simply one-shot everything (especially if using an Intergalatic Phoenix or G-Buster), making it the most effective method to get BP post-game.